# java - Hebrew characters over network are received as question marks

Tags: java, unicode, udp

Here's the scenario:
I have a simple client and server Java programs.
The client sends a Hebrew string to the server: א ב ג space-separated.

The client code that sends the datagram:

```
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(msg.getBytes("UTF-8"), msg.getBytes("UTF-8").length);
packet.setSocketAddress(targetSock);
this.sock.send(packet);
```

The msg is of type String and it contains the Hebrew characters (from an android EditText object)

Wireshark shows the string is as follows: d7 90 20 d7 91 20 d7 92

0x20 is the space and the Hebrew characters are d7 90(1,2).

The code on the server that receives the message:

```
receivedata = new byte[size];
DatagramPacket recv_packet = new DatagramPacket(receivedata, receivedata.length);
inSocket.receive(recv_packet);
String msg = new String(receivedata, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
System.out.println("[" + recv_packet.getSocketAddress() + "]: " + msg);
```

The println() call prints "? ? ?" but it could be explained by the editor failing to print unicode chars. However when the server sends this string (msg) back to the client, the "? ? ?" is being sent instead of the original string.

What am I doing wrong? How do I prevent this transformation of characters?

Comment: The code you show for sending and receiving is correct. The problem must be somewhere else, like in the code you use to display the string on the screen.

Comment: Set your editor and your System.out to the UTF-8 character encoding, then try again.

Comment: If my code is correct, why do I see the "? ? ?" In wireshark in the response packet? At what point can the data itself be manipulated?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending characters through java through CMD and see if it works. For example, run java println(HEBREW CHAR), see if it passes through there. It could be an issue with the server the way it's interpreting it.

Answer (score 0):

i had this kind of problem so i made a "dictonary" of letters and made א to be a ב to be b and so on , and before convert it to english made some header that will tell the app when read that it need to be transform back to hebrew.
for example the word אבא will be NOWֱֹֹ!_!ENGLISHaba